# Flask: Download a .zip file using a GET request

Tags: python, flask, download, response-headers

Flask v1.1.2, Python v3.7

I'm trying to get Flask to send me a .zip file it generates based on the GET request.

I have a page where the user can click a download button, which issues a GET request and parses a key as value. Based on this key the .zip file is created and moved to my `/static` folder. Below the handler that gets executed:

```py
    def download(self):
        key = request.args['action']
        zip_location = os.path.join(app.static_folder, "files.zip")
        res = self.recorder.down.download(key, zip_location)
        return send_file("static/files.zip", as_attachment=True)
```

I tried sending the file using `send_file`, `send_from_directory`, `app.send_static_file`, but they all result in the same strange error occurring:

```
Serving Flask app "webapp.webUI" (lazy loading) 
Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
Debug mode: on
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/somepath/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 506, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/home/pi/somepath/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py", line 45, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2021 13:34:58] "GET /download?action=20210216+16u11s19 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Google doesn't help much, I've been searching the cause of the error for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
from flask import Flask, request
# set the project root directory as the static folder, you can set others.
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

@app.route('/download')
def download():
    return app.send_static_file('files.zip')
```

Comment: As i described, I already tried ```app.send_static_file```. But didn't try setting the static url. So I set it as you described, But it does not fix the issue. I get the same error as I described in my original post

Comment: Ok, so I am using flask by registering endpoints manually using ```self.app.add_url_rule```, which seems to cause the error. I tried your suggestion using ```@app.route```, and it works. 

So good to know it would work, now to get it working using ```add_url_rule```

Comment: unfortunately this sol did not work for me :(